# Large Dynamic expressions and responsive UI's

Tags: plotting, dynamic, gui-construction

I have a `ListLinePlot` with 40,000 points. When it's displayed on-screen the input fields are not responsive (text appears slowly well after the user is done typing). The code looks something like this:

```
DynamicModule[{plot, var},
Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[var],String],
    Dynamic[Refresh[plot, None]]
}],
Initialization :> (plot = makePlot[])
]

makePlot[] := ListLinePlot[{#, Sin[#] + RandomReal[0.1]} & /@ 
    Subdivide[0, 10, 40000], ImageSize -> 500]
```

So even when I use `Refresh[plot, None]` it still causes the `InputField` to suffer. I'd prefer to use `TrackedSymbols :> {plot}` so that it can be updated when I need it to.

I've worked around this by resampling the plot and displaying fewer points. Also, rasterizing the plot works, but that's not really what I want to do. Is there a good way to control the Notebook frontend so that the displayed plot is not impacting other elements around it?

Comment: Sooner or later (depends on a machine too) the amount of boxes in a notebook will affect the performance, probably of a whole notebook. It takes more effort but is often a good idea to really work with gutted versions of big plots / images to improve performance. You can still add interactivity on top of a rasterized background. How this case can be improved depends on what exactly are you doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Kuba. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems other frameworks don't have this issue - like Plotly in JavaScript. Is this because behind the scenes those frameworks are already optimizing what's shown? Perhaps the "rigor" of Mathematica allows for graphical overload on purpose. Is there a good Option to use with `ListLinePlot` to improve the efficiency of the plot?

Comment: One thing to try before drastic changes is to do Graphics+Line to make sure that only essentials are there. I do not know much about this issue in other frameworks. At some point vector grafics have that problem, there are comercial JS packages that serve exactly this purpose.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 12.0 also have access to 12.1 beta